# MailChimp API 3.0 Invalid Resource Error

Tags: json, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am simply trying to add a new member to a MailChimp list. But I keep getting the following error and can't quite understand why:

```
type: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/
title: Invalid Resource
status: 400
detail: The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.
instance:
errors:
0:
field:
message: Schema describes object, NULL found instead
```

This is quite odd because I am sending the exact object in the body as detailed in the exampled from the docs:

```
{"email_address":"urist.mcvankab+3@freddiesjokes.com", "status":"subscribed"}
```

I have tried the call in Postman as well the MailChimp Playground. Am I omitting something in the JSON here?

Comment: Having the same exact error message. I've got a support ticket open with them. Hopefully, I can post a resolution here soon.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any solutions here?

Answer (score 13):

So I was stuck as well, turns out you need to have "merge_fields". Make it an empty object,

```
{
    "email_address": "blahblar@blarblah.com",
    "status": "subscribed",
    "merge_fields": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Wish that would be marked as required in the documentation. I suppose setting skip_merge_validation would also do the trick.

Comment: @MattCosentino considering I "solved" this 4.5 years ago, it's kinda sad that the docs haven't been updated to account for this.

Comment: "merge_fields" should reflect segments that exist in Audience Members. After I added the missing fields, mine worked.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you encode your post data as json. For example in python:

```
import requests
import json

data = {
  "email_address": "test_email@gmail.com",
  "status": "subscribed",
  "merge_fields": {}
}

result = requests.post(<YOUR URL>, auth=<YOUR AUTH CREDS>, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in url. You must have members on the url end:

```
  url: 'https://blabla.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/blabla/members',
```

Answer (score 0):

i was working with node application and this worked for me, instead of using

```
 url: 'https://blabla.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}/members'
```

try this JavaScript object:

```
const data = {
members:[{
email_address: email,
  status: "subscribed",
  merge_fields: {
    FNAME : firstName,
    LNAME : lastName  }
  }]
};
```

and use url:

```
url: "https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}"
```

Note: you must convert JavaScript object to JSON

Answer (score 0):

Even if the `merge_fields` aren't marked as required they are, to bypass the requirement you can pass the query parameter `{ skipMergeValidation: true }` as the third parameter in the `addListMember` request. You can see the doc and the implementation below:

- Add a new member to the list.
- @param {String} listId The unique ID for the list.
- @param {module:model/AddListMembers1} body
- @param {Object} opts Optional parameters
- @param {Boolean} opts.skipMergeValidation If skip_merge_validation is true, member data will be accepted without merge field values, even if the merge field is usually required. This defaults to false.
- @return {Promise} a {@link [https://www.promisejs.org/|Promise}](https://www.promisejs.org/%7CPromise%7D), with data of type {@link module:model/ListMembers2}

```
this.addListMember = function(listId, body, opts) {
  return this.addListMemberWithHttpInfo(listId, body, opts)
    .then(function(response_and_data) {
      return response_and_data.data;
  });
}
```